# I want to reverse a string and i have written the code for it but it's not giving any output

Tags: python, list

The code is not giving any output.

I've tried storing the words in a list using input().split(".") and then running the for loop from len(list)-1 to 0 and appending it to another list but the other list is not getting populated.

```
s1= list()
a = list(map(str, input().rstrip().split(".")))
for i in range(len(a)-1,0):
  s1.append(a[i]+".")
print(s1)
```

Input text: 'this.is.a.test'

Expected output should be ['test','a','is','this']

Acual output is this []

Comment: Your range is empty, because the starting index is greater than the ending index, therefore your `for` loop executes zero times.  You need to add a third parameter to `range()` that's -1, so that you step in reverse.

Comment: The range is empty because the user is giving it. Oh! Now, I understand the problem but then how am I going to assign the actual range when it is calculated after running the program? :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop does not run, because the `start` of `range` is larger than the `end`. You need a `step` of -1 to run from high values to lower ones.
But you have to remember, that `end` is not included:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    s1.append(a[i])
```

But in python, you should avoid to iterate over an index, but iterate over elements of the list, to run in reverse, use `reversed`:

```
for element in reversed(a):
    s1.append(element)
```

which is the same as

```
s1 = list(reversed(a))
```

Putting all together you get:

```
text = input()
parts = text.rstrip().split(".") # no need for map, because split returns a list of strings.
print(".".join(reversed(parts)))
```